# How to create relationships between models that are found on different DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I am developing an application following the DDD pattern.

I have the following contexts for employee management and user account management called

> EmployeeManagementContext

and

> UserAccountManagementContext

Both contexts are on a separate project.
The project for employee management has the following models.

```
public class Employee  
{  
    public int Id { get; private set; }  
    public string Name { get; private set; }  
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; private set; }  
}
```

The project for user account management has the following models.

```
public class Employee  
{  
    public int Id { get; private set; }  
    public string Name { get; private set; }   
}

public class UserAccount  
{  
    public int Id { get; private set; }  
    public string Username { get; private set; }  
    public string Password { get; private set; }  
}
```

EmployeeManagementContext

```
public class EmployeeManagementContext : DbContext  
{  
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }  
}
```

UserAccountManagementContext

```
public class UserAccountManagementContext : DbContext  
{  
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }  
}
```

I can successfully migrate both context by having different context keys but the problem is I loose the relationship between the Employee and UserAccount models.

[image: Wrong Employee to UserAccount relationship]

Basically, the business rules that I need to implement between the two models are as follow:

> An Employee may or may not have a UserAccount.
>   A UserAccount is owned by exactly one Employee only.

This means that I should have a one to zero-or-one relationship between Employee and UserAccount like the diagram below.

[image: Correct Employee to UserAccount relationship]

> Please disregard the wrong relationship notation, its seems to be a limitation of the tool I am using but it is a one-to-zero-or-one relationship I assure you.

I tried the following configurations in UserAccount project:

```
public class UserAccountConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserAccount>  
{  
    HasKey(x => x.Id);  

    Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);  
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>  
{  
    HasKey(x => x.Id);  

    Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);  

    HasOptional(x => x.UserAccount)
        .WithRequired(x => x.Employee);
}  

public class UserAccountManagementContext : DbContext  
{  
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }  

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserAccountConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeeConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The above configurations result to an error because Employee table already exist because of the EmployeeManagementContext in employee management project.

If I try to add the following configuration in EmployeeConfiguration of employee management project,

> ToTable("Users");

EF doesn't complain anymore and creates a Users table which then creates the relationship I need between Employee and UserAccount. But the problem is, if I try to query Employee/Users in UserAccountManagementContext, it doesn't contain anything and I don't think its good design to keep on creating smaller tables that is derived from the orginal table because it will only clutter the database, right?...

I would greatly appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should focus more on the domain and less on the database.

From what I can see, you have two Aggregates (`Employee` and `UserAccount`), in possible 2 *bounded contexts* (I can't name them as I don't have enough data). In general it's not recommended to force any invariant in a *strongly consistent* manner between the two Aggregates but there are exceptions. They may be as well in different databases, having different technologies. Let's now see how you can enforce the two invariants:

> An Employee may or may not have a UserAccount.

This can be modeled with a nullable `UserAccountId` on a `Employee`, without any low level database references. Depending on the business rules, when an UserAccound is *deleted* (if this is a valid business operation on it), using a Saga/Process manager, you can set to `null` the corresponding `UserAccountId` in the `Employee` that had this account.

> A UserAccount is owned by exactly one Employee only.

The simplest way to enforce this invariant is of technological nature: create an unique index on the `UserAccountId`. Other solutions imply using Sagas but are not as good as this one, for example would permit for a short period of time for the invariant to be broken.

Comment: Ok, here is how I understand your answer.

It is ok to ignore that fact that Employee and UserAccount doesn't have a relationship (foreign key constraint) because I can enforce the constraint myself through messaging between bounded context anyways?

Therefore, models/tables in DDD doesn't need to have relationship constraint?

Comment: @devpro101 yes, exactly. You should focus more on the relationships from the business point of view

Comment: I see, its very interesting thank you. I guess I am still thinking more from a database-driven approach rather than DDD. Please let me process this new info that you shared.

Comment: @devpro101 it's hard to not think in databases/relations/tables anymore but you will succeed eventually; just don't give up.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. And no, I will not give up. I like the idea of DDD, I just need more time to understand it fully.